# how can i represent $an^c+b$ as a function where i'm replacing n with $an^c+b$ x amount of times

Tags: calculus

the problem i have is that i want a function that represents n being replaced by $an^c+b$ x amount of times i have yet to make one for $an^c+b$ but i have made one for an+b which was $r\left(x\right)=a^xn+\sum_{k=0}^{\left(x-1\right)}a^kb$ this function represent if i wanted n to be replaced twice i would do r(2) of the equation while replacing a with 2 and b with 1 since x is the number of replacements so the question i'm asking is can you make a function for when i want to replace n with $an^c+b$

https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ypyqlz9qg1

Comment: no im asking if i wanted to replace n with $an^c+b$ x amount of times what would the function look like. for example the first replacement if i was replacing n with $2n^2+1$ is $2n^2+1$ the second replacement is $2(2n^2+1)^2+1$ as you can see n was replaced each time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $g(n)=an^c+b$.
Then $f(x)=g^x(n)$, where we're using $g^k$ to denote the $k$-fold composition of $g$.
In other words,

$$f(x)=g(g(\dots g(n)\dots))=\underbrace{\Big(g\circ g\circ \dots \circ g\Big)}_{x \text{ times}}(n)$$